# Drupal - Mixed content error when using ssl certificate

Tags: ssl, drupal, drupal-7

I had a drupal installation working fine. I tried to migrate that one on a Docker Container runing behind a nginx reverse proxy. Everything seems fine but i have some .js and .css files that can't load because in drupal they are linked with http. The error is:

```
Mixed Content: The page at https://proxy.xx.xx/ was loaded
over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet
http://proxy.xx.xx/sites/default/files/css/css_xE-rWrJf-
fncB6ztZfd2huxqgxu4WO-qwma6Xer30m4.css'. This request has been
blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I have something like 7 of them and i can't find where those files are called in drupal or how to change the http to https.

Best regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, so I got to work by adding the following to the Drupal settings.php:

```
$conf['reverse_proxy'] = TRUE;
$base_url = 'https://whatever-your-domain-is.com';
$conf['reverse_proxy_addresses'] = array('internal_nginx_proxy_ip');
$conf['reverse_proxy_header'] = 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR';
```

This works for jwilder's [nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) container(s) together with JrCs' [letsencrypt companion](https://github.com/JrCs/docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion) container. The nginx container is handling the HTTPS/SSL (certificates) and talks HTTP with the Drupal-container internally. The Drupal container only needs to be run with the 3 ENV VARS VIRTUAL_HOST, LETSENCRYPT_HOST, LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL for everything to be set up and work its magic.

Only downside: The Drupal container's apache logs show the internal IP of the nginx proxy. But the nginx logs show the correct client IPs and Drupal apparently gets them right as well, so it's only a minor nuisance for me.

I guess the additions to the settings.php should also be applicable to custom/manual setups.

Answer (score -1):

We found what was wrong. Drupal was communicating with the Nginx proxy without ssl. Some config and it was ok.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the config changes that fixed this issue so it can aid future users?

Comment: Probably they enabled SSL traffic from Nginx proxy to Drupal. Solution from @Wilhelm Uschtrin is prefered because is more performative (no double SSL encryption) and simpler to configure (you just configure SSL in the external end, the Nginx proxy in this case).

Comment: Is this a thing? Giving "correct answer" flag to yourself?